# Javascript Canvas in ASP.net

Tags: c#, javascript

I’m trying to draw an image on a canvas in a Visual Studio application and then have that image get displayed on a PDF file after clicking a button.  I’m using javascript and C#.  So far I created a Web Page called “A” and in the .aspx page I created a canvas and button, but I’m unsure how I can get this image in the .aspx.cs page (where it says “**Image Here**”) so it can write to the PDF file.  I’m pretty sure my code currently puts my canvas image in base 64.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
//A.aspx:
//Create canvas and save as base 64
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#saveButton').click(saveDrawing);
        });
    </script>  
</head>
<canvas id ="canvas1" class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
  <input type="button" name="saveButton" id="saveButton" value="Save Drawing">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function saveDrawing() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
          //window.open(imgData);  //Not sure if I need this or not
      }
```

```
//A.aspx.cs: Code Behind
public void Method(string A)
{
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(
        pdfReader, 
        new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)
    );
    AcroFields pdfForm = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
    //This is where I need to get the image from A.aspx
    pdfForm.SetField("Picture is", (**Image Here**)); 
}
```

Comment: You need to invoke the `Method` by using ajax.  Have you decorated that method with the `WebMethod` attribute?

Comment: No, I have not used ajax in this application.  Is there another way to pass the image from the .aspx page to the .aspx.cs code? How would I add the WebMethod attribute to this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdncP/) with the basics of what you need to do.  Since you are using Asp.Net, your whole page is in a form.  When you click the submit button it should post the data from the canvas in a hidden field and you can grab the data from `imageData` in the page load.

I am not sure if you will have to do any conversion of the data before you try to save it to the PDF but this should give you a good start.